# Make xgamma change permanent

Tags: debian, gnome, colors

I've recently installed Debian Jessie with Gnome3 on my laptop, and the default gamma settings of the screen are quite off. I corrected them using `xgamma`, but the changes this command makes are not permanent.

I've tried putting the command in `~/.xinitrc`, but that did not work..

The gamma gets reset whenever I unlock my laptop (or boot it, or wake from suspend, etc). What scripts are typically triggered upon unlock? I'm fairly unfamiliar with how these things are managed.